# Pivot tables Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

I'm totally flabbergasted

I have this line of code and I get this error everytime. I've tried so many things, putting it into variables, checking if all of the names are correct, clearing the cache, nothing seems to work.

```
Sheets("Uren verschil per vestiging").PivotTable("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("jaar mutatie").PivotItem(Year(Date)).Visible = True
```

Comment: Perhaps that particular year is not in the data?

Comment: I checked, it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the syntax is off by one s:

```
Sheets("Uren verschil per vestiging").PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("jaar mutatie").PivotItems(CStr(Year(Date))).Visible = True
```

### Edited 20160212 to add an additional s after "PivotItem" and to add CStr around the Year function.

Comment: I just tried this but this doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: I just spotted another missing s and it seems to help to convert the year to a string first: Sheets("Uren verschil per vestiging").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("jaar mutatie").PivotItems(CStr(Year(Date))).Visible = True